# Exchange project files between different versions of Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere

Is there a way to work collaboratively on a Premiere Project when one person has e.g. Premiere Pro CC and the other one CS6?
If I open a Premiere Pro CS6 project file, I have to copy and convert it. If I do this, the person working with Premiere CS6 won't be able to open the project file I created. Of course I could use EDL files, but this isn't really effective when using effects and stuff in Premiere ... so, is there a way to make the projects backwards compatible? (In InDesign for example, you can save project files as IDML rather than INDD, allowing for other people working with CS4 or newer to open the project file)

Comment: EDLs and other such intermediary formats are the best I know of.  I don't work with CC, but I'm pretty sure they don't have a save as old version option sadly.

Comment: Yes, sadly :/ I was hoping maybe there's a plugin or something like that for that functionality ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of effects, it is not possible to explain exactly
Because the CS6 version is definitely not comparable to the CC version

But for example, you can open the CC 2020 version in the lower version
Follow the instructions below:

The indirect and unreasonable way (which often works without problems) is this:

1. Make a backup copy of the prproj file that you want to open in the older version and save it somewhere.
2. Rename the mentioned prproj file and change its extension to 7z.
3. Unzip it with a program that opens zip files such as winrar or 7zip.
4. Now rename it again and add the prproj extension to the end of the uncompressed file.
5. Open this file in a program that can edit text (for example, Windows notepad) and pay attention to the fourth line, you will see a text like this:

```
<Project ObjectID = "1" ClassID = "62ad66dd-0dcd-42da-a660-6d8fbde94876" Version = "36">
```

6. Reduce the number in the version section (36 in the text above) (for example to 29) and save the file.
7. Now open the above file in Premiere, you should see a message that tells you that the file is old and should be saved with a new name. Open a word processor and change the version rate, save and try again.

- If you do not see the file extensions, open an explorer window (for example, drive C or my computer) and click on Options from the View menu, navigate to the View tab in the window that opens, and in the list of available options, select Hide extensions. Find for known file types and uncheck it and close the window by pressing Ok.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what @Amer said plus for a shortcut there's an app that can 'downgrade' your project online - http://joshcluderay.com/downgrade-premiere-project-converter/

the trade off is, it always sets the version to 1 so 'some' effects and attributes might be lost in the process. I found that for your everyday editing this doesn't affect anything unless you're using titles (type).